# How to correct print 2D array

Tags: php, oop

I created a two-dimensional array

```
class MyArray
{
    public $arr=array();

    public function create()
    {
        for($i=0;$i<=4;$i++)
        {
            for($j=0;$j<=4;$j++)
            {
                $this->arr[$i][$j]=0;
            }
        }
    }

    public function print()
    {
        for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
        {
            for($j=0;$j<5;$j++)
            {
                echo $this->arr[$i][$j] . " ";
            }
        }
    }
}

$arr1= new MyArray();
$arr1->create();
$arr1->print();
```

but when I display it looks like this:

> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

What to do to look like this:

> 0 0 0 0 0
>     0 0 0 0 0 
>     0 0 0 0 0
>     0 0 0 0 0 
>     0 0 0 0 0

Comment: You'd need to echo a line break in each outer loop. For html it'd be `echo '<br>';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `<br />` tag after the inner `for` loop, like this:

```
public function print(){
    for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
        for($j=0;$j<5;$j++){
            echo $this->arr[$i][$j] . " ";
        }
        echo "<br />";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot know if you are making a web page, you will either need to `echo`/`print` a newline character `\n`  or an HTML break (`<br>` or `<br />`) to be the second statement in the outer loop of `MyArray::print`, depending on the context (HTML5 or HTML 4.01/XHTML 1.0).

Answer (score 0):

This is print in single line because you are not using line break.
You need to add `<br>` in another for loop as following:

```
public function print(){
 for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
    for($j=0;$j<5;$j++){
        echo $this->arr[$i][$j] . " ";
    }
    echo "<br />";
 }
}
```